# UIAlertViews: Where do they live?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uialertview

My app has lots of pages and lots of times when it needs to display an alertview with a progress indicator or an activity indicator. Can I just declare these as class properties in my rootviewcontroller and show/hide them from other places or is that bad practise. I have URL requests that are processed by delegates (which increment a progress bar). I'm worried that having it as a property of the rvc will make it kinda vulnerable. But at the same time, I don't want to make a billion alertviews because that might get messy too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly go the route of having a single UIAlertView somewhere like your AppDelegate, but that defeats the purpose of MVC. The better approach would be to have each view controller manage its own alert view.

That being said, it's not really necessary to pop up an alert view if all you need is an activity indicator/progress view to show the user that you are doing some work. Alert views, by-and-large, are obtrusive to the user experience and should really only be used to *alert* the user that something is going on, i.e. something went wrong and demands their attention immediately. For pure progress/loading, adding the indicator as a subview of your main view should suffice, and smooths the overall user experience.